# How to specify a max vw size for all elements that use vw units?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I’m using `vw` on font, padding and margin sizes. I design mobile first. Everything looks good up until around 700 pixels, at which point fonts start too look far too big.

I would like to ensure that fonts don’t grow larger than a specified value. Is it possible to set max font size?

Here's some example code where I use `vw`. But after `700px` it starts to look too big to read comfortably.

```
#intro h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 8vw;
}
```

My only thought was to use a media query and specify a pixel font size but that seems like the wrong tool for the job. I would have to create media queries for all elements that use `vw` units.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

There is no such things as min-font-size or max-font-size.

Use `media queries` for this case;

Expand the snippet to play with it.

```css
#intro h1 {
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 8vw;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  #intro h1 {
    font-size: 3.5rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="intro"><h1>Coucou</h1></div>
```

Comment: Genius. For a while, I thought I was going to have to use FitText.

Answer (score 1):

You can use min() / clamp() for this.

eg.

```
font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 2.5vw, 4rem);
```

There are examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp